# How add images of different size to Android Studio easily?

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the following images from design and I would like to add them to my Android Studio project. They are the same image for different sizes.

[image]

I remember I was able to drag and drop them into the file directory in AS and they will fall into the right folders. However, it's now saying these folder already existing and I cannot drag and drop them.

My question: is there an easy way to import these images besides drag and drop each one individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I learned I need to do copy/paste instead of drag/drop.

1. select all the `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdip` folders and do `cmd + c`
2. select the `res` folder in AS and do `cmd + v`

The images will fall into the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question and I will answer, but let us go a little deeper into this rationale. You need to create images for screens with different sizes.

**1 . SVG file :**

I suggest you use images in SVG format. They can work well on all screens.

File > New > Vector asset

**2 . Use plugin ( Material Design Icon Generator ) :**

This plugin help you to set material icon in your app resources. Its also generate vector icons that work well on all screens . Here is page of this plugin :

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14170-material-design-icon-generator

**3 . Copy & Paste :**

Move your images to the following folders (create them if they do not exist):

```
src/main/res/drawable
src/main/res/drawable-hdpi
src/main/res/drawable-mdpi
src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi
src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi
src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi
```

Comment: Yiur answer doesn't solve their problem.  Also, SVG is good for certain types of images and horrible for others-  SVGs don't work at all for photos (they're several times the original size and take a ton of processing power).  You shouldn't just blindly suggest them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok then You may try this
Copy the image from your local folder and right-click on the folder of the AS project  you want to add the image and select paste.

You can change the size at first you create that image.